# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable using pandas_ta and yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, algorithmic-trading, yfinance, pandas-ta

I am trying to calculate the macd of a stock using the panada_ta library.

The function I created to do so (will post below) works perfectly fine when I run it on it's own, but I am trying to call it within a calc_technicals() functions that calls several methods to conduct technical analysis on stocks, but it says my df is of type NoneType

```
def calc_macd(self, stock: Stock):
    macd = ta.macd(stock._df["Close"])
    stock._macd = macd["MACD_12_26_9"].tail()[-1]
    stock._macd_slow = macd["MACDs_12_26_9"].tail()[-1]

def calc_technicals(self):
    for stock in self._watchlist:
        self.calc_macd(stock)
        self.calc_rsi(stock)
        self.calc_vwap(stock)
        self.calc_ema(stock)
```

This is the error I get when I call the calc_technicals() method

[image]

Comment: Is there `None` or similar value in `self._watchlist`?

Comment: No there isn't it is populated with custom Stock objects

Comment: So it appears that `macd` is None or something similar on the second line of the `calc_macd` function. Is it possible that `ta.macd(stock._df["Close"])` is returning None? Maybe that function does something but then has an empty `return` statement?